# ML350 G6 drive not detected

Tags: hp, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

I have an ML350 G6 that I have bought some new drives (HP P/N: 507129-004) for. According to the drive specs these are compatible with the G6 but the SAS controller (p410i) is not detecting them. The controller works fine as I have another set of disks that I have xcp-ng installed on working perfectly on the server.

Seeing as the raid controller is fine, server works perfectly with other disks and assuming the 507129-004 disks are not faulty (I have 15 and they all act the same) what else could prohibit the p410i sas raid controller from detecting the drives?

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: Bad cable? Loose connection? Is power getting to the backplane?

Comment: I swapped the old disks back into the same cage and all working perfectly, so that implies cage, cables, backplane all ok. I'm leaning towards bunch of bad disks or firmware issue with p410i or disks.

Comment: How do you know the drives aren't being detected?

Comment: The hypervisor {xcp-ng} fails to find it. Going through loads of permutations and accessing p410 configuration at start seems to indicate drive firmware being out of date. Going to explore smarts tart boot option next. Anyone else had to resort to such measures?

Comment: This server is well outside the window of support which is a risk to your business, you really need to replace it.

Comment: I am aware of the age, thanks. No worries not business critical.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a misunderstanding about how the Smart Array RAID controller and configuration operates.

**If you insert new disks, they need to be configured into a Logical Drive before they'll be visible to the operating system.**

In this case, you should explain what your intention is:

- Are you trying to expand an existing array?
- Are you interested in creating a new group of disks as a separate array from the existing?

Luckily, there's a manual:

http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02289065.pdf

Comment: Thanks figured that out but prior to this the disks needed to get a firmware upgrade via SPP.